# Create DNS record to External Hostname in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, networking, dns, windows-server-2012, hostname

I received a request to add the following record to the hosts file on all PC's in my company:

```
ExternalHostname.hosting.local   172.123.456.789
```

The ExternalHostname is a SAP server located in a rented Datacenter, and our company connects to the servers by using a VPN connection.

It seems to me that it is better to add an A Record in the Forward Lookup Zone on my local DNS server (Windows Server 2012).

However, when I do this, it creates the following record within to following folders

```
SRV2012AD > Forward Lookup Zone > local > hosting > ExternalHostname(record)
```

the FQDN becomes:

```
ExternalHostname.hosting.local.CompanyDomainName.local
```

The forwarding is important because is being used in custom based webapplication. Everything works when I change the hostname to ip, but that will not be possible in Production.

Does anyone know if there is a solid and maintainable solution for this?

Would be super awesome!

K

Comment: I'd just name it `ExternalHostname.CompanyDomain.local` then. Is that not acceptable for some reason? I.e. certificate mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new forward lookup zone in DNS with the name `ExternalHostname.hosting.local`.

Create a new A record in that zone with a blank name and an IP of `172.123.456.789`.

http://www.itgeared.com/articles/1058-how-to-be-authoritative-for-single-host/